# Tell atom editor to watch/index only subset of files in repo

Tags: atom, indexing

I have a repository that is very large, and has a very large number of sub-directories and files. When I attempt to open a single subdir of the repository with Atom (which is 13MB), it will crash repeatedly.

I don't get any helpful logs in the `nohup.log` and the crash log doesn't show anything helpful either.

When I tried opening the repo in VS Code I get this message:

```
"Visual Studio Code is unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace" (error ENOSPC)
```

And it sends me to [this error message page link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc). It is also able to actually open and display the files I'm looking at.

**Is there a way to get atom to not index all the files in the repo and to only focus on a limited subset of files so it doesn't crash trying to index everything?**

**Is there a way to tell atom to only focus on the files in the subdir that I am opening?**

**Alternatively, is there a way to tell Atom not to index everything automatically and instead have it refresh the file explorer only when I tell it to, such as manually hitting a file explorer refresh button? *(this is the behavior of VS Code with large repos)***

Comment: How is this question Ubuntu related? Both, Atom and VSCode, will ignore files in your VCS ignore-files (e.g. `.gitignore`).

Comment: What other stack exchange do you suggest I post this to? I thought here might be best because it's specifically happening on my computer that is running ubuntu, and I have no other way of checking if it happens on another OS that supports Atom because the repo is proprietary (work related).

Also I don't want to edit the git ignore every time I edit a different subdirectory. I wasn't sure if there was even a way to tell atom *not* to index everything automatically and have it manually refresh the file explorer when I tell it to (that's what VS code does for large repos).

Comment: Probably Super User